# Retrieve all contents of Zoho module via REST API c#

Tags: c#, api, rest, zoho, zoho-deluge

I am trying to get the full contents of my modules From Zoho to our local Server. The deluge code does work as it returns to me the data which is being sent via the API. However, once it reaches the API, it is null. Any idea?

Below is the deluge code:

```
// Create a map that holds the values of the new contact that needs to be created
evaluation_info = Map();
evaluation_info.put("BulkData",zoho.crm.getRecords("Publishers"));

data = Map();
data.put(evaluation_info);

response = invokeurl
[
  url :"https://zohoapi.xxxxx.com/publisher/publish"
  type :POST
  parameters:data
  connection:"zohowebapi"
];
info data; (data returns all the data from publishers)
```

Here is my ASP.NET core restful API. It does ping it and create the file but the content of the file is null.

```
Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PublisherController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("[action]"), HttpPost("[action]")]
    
    public void Publish(string data)
    {
        (it's already null when it comes here. why?)

        string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        string path = @"C:\storage\journalytics_evaluationsv2.json";

        using (var file = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(JSONresult.ToString());
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

What am I missing? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Zoho support, the solution he offered was to loop through the data in order to get all the contents from a module (if they are more than 200 records. With the solution provided, one doesn't really need the deluge code anymore as long as you have the ZOHO api set to your account in code. This was my final solution. This solution is not scalable at all. It's best to work with the BULK CSV.

```
//  Our own ZohoAPI which lets us connect and authenticate etc. Yours may look slightly different
ZohoApi zohoApi = new ZohoApi();
zohoApi.Initialize();
ZCRMRestClient restClient = ZCRMRestClient.GetInstance();

 var allMedicalJournals = new List<ZCRMRecord>();
 for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
 {
     List<ZCRMRecord> accountAccessRecords2 = 
    restClient.GetModuleInstance("Journals").SearchByCriteria("Tag:equals:MedicalSet", i, 200).BulkData.ToList();

    foreach (var newData in accountAccessRecords2) 
         allMedicalJournals.Add(newData);
 }
```